# Unlocking spreadsheet files quickly - follow-up

Tags: ruby, file, locking

I recently posted a program I made to unlock spreadsheet files( see [also](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111840/unlocking-spreadsheet-files-quickly) ), I've taken all of your advice and made it more Ruby like, it has no shell commands in it, and uses `FileUtils`

I personally think it looks a whole lot cleaner and a whole lot more Ruby like. I would like a critique on my work so far, and would like some pointers if possible.

Source:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

require 'fileutils'

def spreadsheet_unlocker
    puts "Enter Folio # if unlocking multiple seperate with comma followed by space."
    folios = gets.chomp
    folios.split(', ').each do |input_folio|
        lockfile = "/my/dir.~lock.#{input_folio}.ods#"
        if input_folio =~ /^\d{7}/ 
            if File.exist?( lockfile )
                puts "Unlock file?"
                input = gets.chomp
                    if input =~ /y/i
                     FileUtils.rm( lockfile )
                     puts "File unlocked."
                else
                    puts "You went through that trouble for no reason..."
                end
            else
                puts <<-EDE.gsub(/^\s*>/, ' ') 
                >
                >Lockfile not found for Folio # #{input_folio}"
                >
                >If the file name doesn't match the folio number, get the file name
                >and use that instead of the Folio number...
                >
                EDE
                spreadsheet_unlocker
            end
        else
            puts <<-EDF.gsub(/^\s*>/, ' ')
            >
            >What part of 'Folio #' is hard to understand? 7 DIGITS"
            >
            >If the file name doesn't match the folio number, get the file name
            >and use that instead of the Folio number...
            >
            EDF
            spreadsheet_unlocker
        end
    end
end
spreadsheet_unlocker
```

Example usage:

```
Enter Folio # if unlocking multiple seperate with comma followed by space.
1111111, 2222222, 3333333
Unlock file?
yes
File unlocked.
Unlock file?
yes
File unlocked.
Unlock file?
yes
File unlocked.
```

---

```
Enter Folio # if unlocking multiple seperate with comma followed by space.
2345678

 Lockfile not found for Folio # 2345678"

 If the file name doesn't match the folio number, get the file name
 and use that instead of the Folio number...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job listening to feedback. Keep at it.

- Use two spaces to indent.
- Name your methods verbs, not nouns (e.g., `unlock_spreadsheet`).
- Split on comma and then use `strip` to remove leading and trailing whitespace.
- Rather than calling the method recursively, you may want to put a `loop do` around the method and then `break` when you're done.
- If you run Rubocop, you'll see that your method is too long. Instead, you can move each set of actions inside of `if` and `else` blocks into their own methods.

Comment: Moving the actions into methods sounds like an excellent idea, thanks for the advice!

Comment: I forgot to mention why not use nouns for methods..?

Comment: Nouns for Classes and verbs for methods, because methods do things, and classes have things done to them. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/412870/1935918

Comment: Awh, that makes sense, never thought of it like that, what if I turned the `if else` blocks into a case statement, do you think that would look better?

Comment: Yes, I would definitely try to avoid nested `if`/`else`s. A `case` statement is great if you have more than a couple `elsif`s.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question and embed your revised code at the bottom.

Comment: I'll just make a new thread when it's completely revised